# Error when i start the rails server on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9.1

when i try to start the rails server this error ever appears

```
C:\Arthur\Ruby\Aplicações em ruby\blog>rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Arthur/Ruby/Aplicações em ruby/blog/config.ru:4:in `require': cannot load such file --
C:/Arthur/Ruby/AplicaÃ§Ãµes em ruby/blog/config/environment (LoadError)
    from C:/Arthur/Ruby/Aplicações em ruby/blog/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `ins
tance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `ini
tialize'
    from C:/Arthur/Ruby/Aplicações em ruby/blog/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from C:/Arthur/Ruby/Aplicações em ruby/blog/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eva
l'
.
.
.
```

what i need to do to use ruby on rails ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to advise you to create your application in directory, in which path are only english symbols. Ruby probably can't understand symbols like this 'Aplicações em ruby'